# Why does "^?" appears when using read command with -n argument?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, prompt

This is the small shell script I wrote :

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Tell me something"
read -n 1000 text
```

But when the -n argument is used, I cannot erase my typos as using backspace results in inserting "^?" into the input.

Example input :

> t^?This is my ans^?wer

My question here is why does using **read** with or without the -n argument results in different behaviors and how can I use **read** with the -n argument so I could normally use backspace ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently `-n` disables Readline, which is normally on by default when stdin is interactive. Use `-e` to explicitly enable it.

```
read -n 1000 -e text
```

Comment: Actually, I think it's more accurate to say that enabling Readline with `-e` compensates for whatever `-n` does to input buffering.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to apply the length limit *after* the user has provided input:

```
read -r text
text=${text:0:1000}
echo "You entered ${#text} characters"
```